# Trying to identify some very old Magura rim brakes

Tags: rim-brake

I'm looking to identify some very old rim brakes.  I bought this bike used, and have now ridden it for enough miles that I strongly feel the need to replace at least the brake pads.  No evidence that there is a problem, just a gut feeling that 5000 miles is plenty for one set of pads.

So, I'm attaching pictures.  I once did some research and think I discovered "Magura Move!" in some website archives from well before 2000.  But, the Magura forums look pretty dead, and I would guess I'll get more eyes on the problem here.

I'm looking to replace either the pads, or the entire system with a new one.  I'm also considering the possibility of completely retiring the bike these are attached to.  What I need to know is how likely I am to find new pads for brakes that may be twenty years old, and if not, what measurements will help me ensure that I'm getting a new set appropriate for my bike?

[image: handlebar]
[image: brake mount]

Comment: Magura Move! were sold in the late 90s I believe. Find your local Magura dealer, and take it to them. They should be able to sort you out for some new pads.

Comment: Those brake attachments look a little like post mount... Just all wrong and on the wrong side. No wonder Magura couldn't sell these as well as V-brakes sold at the time. Those must be some of the very, very first hydraulic rim brakes in existence. If you consider ditching the brakes, try to sell them to some retro nut on ebay. They pay quite well for these kinds of parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magura hydraulic rim brakes are a quality product. They still make these and many of the older models are sought-after in the retro mountain bike scene. They are durable and perform very well. From your pictures it seems you have direct mounts on your frame specifically for these brakes, this is now most common on trials bikes.

The brake pad fitting is the same throughout the range, many 3rd party manufacturers produce replacement pads for these brakes and they're no more expensive than other brake pads. Kool Stop, Kashimax and many others are widely available. Google for "Magura Rim Brake Pads"

To remove the pads, remove the wheel and pull them out of the holder. To replace, just push them into the holder. It's that simple.

They may also benefit from being bled and having the fluid replaced. Bleeding and re-filling sounds daunting but it is possible to do at home and the kit is usually inexpensive. Youtube has many videos detailing the process.

Overall, these are good brakes and barring mechanical failure, they should provide you with many more miles of trouble-free usage and good performance.

Comment: That is very much a relief!  After Batman's response I took the bike to a Magura authorized shop, and it's still waiting there for the parts to come in.  But if they really did keep the pads the same size, then I'll not have to do that once I learn how to work on hydraulics.

Comment: The brake pad for this brake is still common indeed. Even better: the brake mounted on a lot of non-sports bicycles still works very similar.
Fluid replacement will give you more accurate braking and more braking power. However, these old brakes almost never stop working unless the cables leak, and they don't leak often.